# Discours indirect: dire que + indicatif / dire + infinitif

Tags: discours-indirect

Voici deux formes de discours indirect.

```
1. Il dit qu'il n'a pas de réponse. (dire que + indicatif)

2. Il dit ne pas avoir de réponse. (dire + infinitif)
```

Sont elles toutes les deux correctes? Y a-t-il une différence entre les deux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les deux sont correctes et la deuxième est plus soutenue.

Elle a pour variante:

> Il dit n'avoir pas de réponse.

À l'oral:

> Y (= il) dit qu'il a pas de réponse.